# In GIMP, is there a way to select only one area by colour or one 'colour island' instead of all pixels by the chosen colour?

Tags: color, gimp, selections

I want to select by colour but I only want to select one 'island of colour', not all pixels of the chosen colour.

For example, in the image below, how would I select-by-colour:

- only the **red** colour island (area) labeled "**A**", or
- only the **white** area labeled "**4**"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer - press "U" for the "Fuzzy Select Tool".

Comment: Note that if you look carefully, not all pixels on the edges are selected, because they are a blend of the shape color and the other shape or background color. If you are creating images the problem can be avoided by using  a layer for each shape.

Comment: If you can mark this answer as the answer to your question it will assist people searching stack exchange.